# Element Position finding - scrollTop fails

Tags: javascript, dom, scroll

I use this code to find the real X/Y position of an element - but i also need to factor in the scroll-position of items too. The scrollTop call never seems to return a value, even when something is scrolled?

```
var x,y;
    y=o.offsetTop;
    x=o.offsetLeft;
    o=o.offsetParent;
    while(o)
    {
        if(o.tagName=="BODY")
            break;
        y+=o.offsetTop+o.scrollTop;
        x+=o.offsetLeft;
        o=o.offsetParent;
    }
    return [x,y];
```

Comment: This solution does work on scrolled elements only not on the body element. I had this problem before and I just couldn't figure it out. I just assumed it just wasn't possible.